# How to use InsertMany properly Mongodb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, ienumerable

Hi I wont to pass some synthetic data to my database with the method InsertMany i have write the flowing code:

My `Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     MongoCRUD db = new MongoCRUD("testClass");

     List<GlobalUrbanPoint> syntheticData = CreateSunfeticData(20);
     db.InsertMultipleRecords<GlobalUrbanPoint>("geo3", syntheticData);

 }
```

My model class:

```
 public class GlobalUrbanPoint 
 {
     [BsonId]
      public ObjectId  Id{ get; set; }
      public string NAME { get; set; }
 }
```

The function for the synthetic data:

```
public static List<GlobalUrbanPoint> CreateSunfeticData(int NumberOfDocumet)
    {
        List<GlobalUrbanPoint> SyntheticList = new List<GlobalUrbanPoint>();

        var SyntheticObject = new GlobalUrbanPoint();
        for (var i = 1; i < NumberOfDocumet; i++)
        {
            SyntheticObject.NAME = (i+1).ToString();
            SyntheticList.Add(SyntheticObject);
        }


        return SyntheticList;
    }
```

And for my operation i use MongoCRUD

```
 public class MongoCRUD
    {
        private IMongoDatabase db;

        public MongoCRUD(string database)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient();
            db = client.GetDatabase(database);
        }

        public void InsertRecord<T>(string table, T record)
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            collection.InsertOne(record);
        }

        public void InsertMultipleRecords<T>(string table, List<T> records) 
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            collection.InsertMany(records);
        }

   }
```

When i run the code i get an error E11000 duplicate key error collection. I check the definition of InsertMany and it takes for arguments `IEnumerable<TDocument> documents`. It is an easy way to convert `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<TDocument>`?
What i need to change my synthetic function or my InsertMultipleRecords funtion. Any sugestion?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging i found that the object that i create in `synthetic function` has the same _id. For that i needed to change the creation of the object, inside of for loop. And my problem it was not in `InsertMultipleRecords`.

```
public static List<GlobalUrbanPoint> CreateSunfeticData(int NumberOfDocumet)
{
    List<GlobalUrbanPoint> SyntheticList = new List<GlobalUrbanPoint>();

    for (var i = 1; i < NumberOfDocumet; i++)
    {
        var SyntheticObject = new GlobalUrbanPoint();
        SyntheticObject.NAME = (i+1).ToString();
        SyntheticList.Add(SyntheticObject);
    }
    return SyntheticList;
}
```